# Windows 10 host and Linux guest, can I swap the two license wise?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, license, qemu

I have Windows 10 64-bit Pro.  I took the free upgrade from a retail copy of Windows 8.1 Pro.

Right now I have a Windows 10 host with a Linux guest.  My system supports VT-x and VT-d for passing a graphics card through from the host to the guest.

I would like to reverse this situation.  Having a Linux host with a Windows 10 guest and the passed-through graphics card for real gaming with it.

I have my digital entitlement associated with my Microsoft account.  If I installed everything like this would I have the right - and keep the entitlement - for it?

Comment: Most setups won't get you the performance you need for gaming. Just as a heads up. In addition with emulation you'd present it with a different kind of hardware so most likely you'd need to at least call Microsoft to activate it again.

Comment: also, you can install linux side by side with windows. It's your choice, but like seth said, that would be better for gaming

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its a bit tricky.

As per the [EULA](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm) (Part 4b for those playing at home)

> b.      Stand-alone software. If you acquired the software as stand-alone software (and also if you upgraded from software you acquired as stand-alone software), you may transfer the software to another device that belongs to you. You may also transfer the software to a device owned by someone else if (i) you are the first licensed user of the software and (ii) the new user agrees to the terms of this agreement. You may use the backup copy we allow you to make or the media that the software came on to transfer the software. Every time you transfer the software to a new device, you must remove the software from the prior device. You may not transfer the software to share licenses between devices.

So, *in theory* ***yes***. According to the official license documents, if you upgrade to Windows 10 from a Retail (transferrable) copy of Windows 8.x you retain the same Retail (transferrable) rights. This has been also been stated by Microsoft officials. [source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/can-i-reinstall-windows-10-once-i-upgrade/c50ad32d-08a5-4273-a941-c353e43a5056?page=4)

*In practice* however, Microsoft's upgrade and licensing systems are incapable of actually *handling* this, so you only get a non-transferrable Windows 10 "Digital entitlement" for that individual machine. [(source)](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/software/operating-systems/1403707/windows-7-and-8-retail-users-cant-transfer-windows-10-after-a) [(source)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/how-do-i-transfer-windows-retail-license-after/6ee1dfe0-8adc-4cce-a46a-748963cf56d1?page=3)

A Windows 10 *digital entitlement* associated with your Microsoft account has no key. Digital entitlements are locked to the machine they were first installed on. Microsoft will only allow you to restore your digital entitlement from your Microsoft Account onto a machine of the same type and manufacturer as the original - because you have to convince it it's the "same machine". Therefore, you can't take an entitlement linked to your account from a Dell machine and restore it onto a Lenovo, or a VM.

So *in practice*, you would have the "right" to do what you propose, but *in reality* you can't. Microsoft seems to have no official workaround, instead issuing individuals with Retail Windows 10 keys on an ad-hoc basis if they complain to MS Support enough.

One way around this would be to [use your windows *8* key with a windows 10 installer](http://www.howtogeek.com/266072/you-can-still-get-windows-10-for-free-with-a-windows-7-8-or-8.1-key/), though phone or chat activation may be needed with an explanation that you have completely deleted your old install. Alternatively, you can also install the VM initially with Windows 8.1 Pro, and then perform the "Free upgrade to Windows 10" procedure again, which still works. Microsoft also officially still give out free upgrades to those using "accessibility software" which is not actually defined or checked anywhere. [(source)](http://www.howtogeek.com/265409/you-can-still-get-windows-10-for-free-from-microsofts-accessibility-site/)

I believe you can run windows in trial mode for a short period of time. This might be a good idea *before* you activate the licence on the VM - it ensures that the VM is good enough for what you want it to do, and is a reasonably safe way to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!

1. Get your Windows license using `wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey`. If it's an OEM machine, look for the Windows license that came with the computer (it's usually on a sticker right on the computer case), otherwise, you're getting a dummy key that says "Yo I'm upgraded from an earlier version of Windows".
2. Create your own Windows 8 ISO using [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows8). You'll need to copy this ISO to an USB key or something.
3. Install Linux
4. Boot your virtual machine on the Windows 8 ISO you just made, use the cd key
5. **If it's an OEM key**, you'll need to activate later your license with a phone call to an automated system. Be sure to activate Windows 8!
6. Reboot the virtual machine
7. [Upgrade to Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10/) the Windows 8 virtual machine.

I don't really recommend doing this because your virtual machine will need to be installed from Windows 8 each time you delete it and create a new one. Upgrading to Windows 10 sends your device's HWID to Microsoft and it's used to determine if it's the same computer you're reinstalling Windows 10 on. Virtual machines have a different HWID than your physical computer and they aren't compatible between Windows 10 installations.

On an unrelated note, since you are switching from Windows 10 to Linux, I would like to show you [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/commandline/wsl/about).

Answer (score -1):

windows 10 is basically hardware based licensing (motherboard, that is). so when youve upgraded your 8.1 windows to 10, you have one license key, it should work for both.

activation goes by online and everything you have on (or had) your MS account will be available to use at the point you switch your configuration and/or reinstall stuff.

so for you, no worries